# Chef library helper function evaluation/load time

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe, chef-infra

I have following recipe (recipes/master.rb):

```
master do
 action :install
end
```

that uses definition (definitions/master.rb)

```
define :master, :action => nothing do
 [...]
 if params[:action] == :install and not master_installed?(master_path)
  #install master code here - above you can see first call of "master_installed?"
 end
 [...]
 if master_installed?(master_path)
  #do something if master has been installed
 end
end
```

that uses library of helpers where "master_installed?" function is specified:

```
module Opscode
 module MyHelpers
 [...]

  def master_installed?(path)
   cmd = shell_out("test -f #{path}/bin/startup_linux.bash")
   if (cmd.exitstatus == 0 and cmd.stderr.empty?)
    return true
   else
    return false
   end
  end

 end
end
```

So I'm using "master_installed?" function twice during runtime. On fresh initial run when master is not installed it should be called twice and scenario should be following:

- `master_installed? => False` (first call in master.rb)
- perform install master procedure
- `master_installed? => True` (second call in master.rb)
- do something after master installation

but actually master_installed? seems to be evaluating only once on the beggining so it looks like:

- `master_installed? => False` (first call in master.rb)
- perform install master procedure
- `master_installed? => False` (second call in master.rb)
- do some post-install stuff after master is installed

so I have to run chef-client twice because:

1. first run installs master because it returns False on "master_installed?"
2. second run does not install master but does the post-install stuff

Comment: You want an LWRP or HWRP here... You are abusing a definition

Comment: Also shelling out to `test -f` is not only slow and bash-specific, but it's also just terrible. Why not use `File.exist?` instead?

Comment: thanks for your comments - LWRP hits the spot